# Complement or object?

Tags: grammar, sentence, objects, complements

> I saw him cross the road.

Is *cross the road* the object of *saw*? Or is it the complement of *him*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this sentence, `to cross the road` is an [*objective predicative complement*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28linguistics%29#Objective_predicative_complements) within the sentence.

Such phrases take the general form:

```
SUBJECT + VERB + OBJECT + COMPLEMENT
```

The object here is clearly `him`.

#### Side note

As far as I'm aware, the "objective complement" is a rather peculiar construct to the English language. Other European languages (I can vouch for French and Spanish at least) require a separate clause, something akin to `I saw that he crossed the road`. (Also perfectly grammatical English, but less natural.)

Answer (score 1):

A verb (cross) cannot be the object.

Break the statement into smaller pieces and the true object becomes more obvious:

> I saw him

'I' subject, 'saw' verb, 'him' accusative object

> he crossed the road

crossing is a separate activity to the seeing